# How to parallel this sql execution in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Two tables are joined using hash join shown in execution plan.

One table has 170 thousand rows and the other table has about 30 million rows, and the result is about 1.6 million rows. The two tables are not partitioned.
The sql is like:

```
select a.*, b.* from a inner join b on a.col1 = b. col1
```

Currently, this sql takes several miniutes to complete, can parallel execution be applied to this sql to make it run faster, if yes which SQL parallel hint I can use, or any other methods. The users of this query complain it take too much time to complete.

Comment: Are users really walking through 1.6 million rows of data?  Or are they doing additional aggregations on the data?  Are you sure that the bottleneck here isn't something like the time required to fetch 1.6 million rows over the wire to whatever process is aggregating or processing the data for the users to consume?  My bias would be to configure Oracle to automatically use parallelism where appropriate and to throttle the degree of parallelism but you could use hints to have the scan on either table go in parallel (assuming your system is configured to allow that).

Comment: what is the "too much time"?  A materialized view may could help you

Comment: Explain plan may be helpful. Tips for asking a good SQL question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1835659.